# Receiving lots of records and storing them in a database in a short time frame

Tags: database, transaction, high-performance

A colleague has challenged me with an interesting question. To be honest I have no idea how to deal with it.

Suppose the following:

> Every 5 minutes you get a new file with one hundred thousand new
>   records. You need to store the records in a database table within
>   these 5 minutes.

- First, I'd stream that file because loading up everything in memory may cause a stack overflow
- Second, inserting data in a batch way

What coding strategy would you use to cope with the amount of data and to stay within this short timeframe for each file you receive?

Comment: Aren't you looking for batch inserts?

Comment: I think batch insert is mandatory. What about files?

Comment: This is going to be highly implementation-specific, but...  In general, you want to wrap the records in batches of transactions.  For example, in Entity Framework, you can insert a hundred records and then do a `SaveChanges()`  With SQLite, you start a transaction, write those same 100 records, and then COMMIT.

Comment: What problem do you expect? I don't foresee any big issues here per se.

Comment: In that file is one row one record? If file is csv format and the db is Oracle 9+, you don't even need to code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bulk Insert Operations are your friend(s).

If it's a straight insert only (new data only in files) simply bulk insert the data directly to the table.  Most databases have utilities to do bulk insert operations, some even expose those libraries to code as well if using command line utilities and batch files seem old fashioned.

If it's an insert/update/delete type of scenario, bulk insert into a staging table and then use RDMS specific technology to update the target table.

For example, SQL Server provides a nice [MERGE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx) command to merge data to a target.

Bulk inserting 100,000 records will only take a second or so.  If your in the insert/update/delete scenario it will take a few more seconds to merge the data from the staging table to the main table.

With this approach you will be able to meet the 5 minute window.

If there is really this amount of data coming in every 5 minutes, then you will need data partitioning strategy as well to help manage the data in the database.

60/5 = 12 * 24 = 288

288*100,000 = 28,800,000 ~29 million records a day. 870 million records per month.

I would develop an archiving/purge strategy as well.

Comment: What kind of archiving/purge strategy would you recommend?

Comment: @Roland - It depends.  Go to your stake holders and find out how long they need the data for.  These requirements will drive the purge/archiving strategy. If this is a transactional system, only keep data that is relevant.  Older data can be purged or archived.  That way you can manage the high water mark of records in the database and have an idea of the storage capacity required to store the data.

Answer (score 0):

My coding strategy would necessarily have to consider how/when you are going to read those records.

Otherwise, if you have no read requirements, I wouldn't even put the records into a database; instead I'd just leave them in the files (or even throw them away).

Your *read requirements* combined with your *ingestion requirements* will dictate what kind of database to use, for one.

The question is rather broad and leaves a lot of information unstated.

I would also consider the schema of those records, such as, number of tables, types of primary keys.

You mention the records are new rather than updates of existing, so a no-SQL database might handle this nicely, depending again on your unstated read requirements.